# Exception "Exception occurred in direct soap call" while trying to save changes in an Einstein Bot

Tags: api, soap, exception, einstein, einstein-chatbot

I get the following exception with Bots:
"ui.services.connection.api.ToolingConnectionException: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Exception occurred in direct soap call".
It happens in the last step of the creation but it's created anyway.
Once created, I can't save changes because I get that exception when I press "Save". (It says 'Saved' but it's not).
I only found one answer that says that the chat settings must be active, and it is active, so that's not the problem.
I tried creating a new one and happens the same.
[image]

Comment: Is this error appearing intermittently or all the time?

Comment: It appears every time I press "Save"..